# Recurring order not recurring product

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, recurring

I have looked high and low but I cant seem to find in Magento natively or an extension to enable customers to create a weekly/monthly order of the same products, these would then be deducted from their saved card/bank details at a set recurring time period and the products despatched.

Can anyone advise if this is possible

Answer (score 1):

There is a "recurring profile" section in Magento but it only works with a few payment types, actually maybe only paypal I cannot remember, and it only allows single product orders and not recurring orders themselves.

There are a few alternative extensions but I am not sure if they will fit your needs. Your best bet would be to contact these extension developers directly and ask for a demo/consult and see if the extensions will work for you.

- [Subscriptions and Recurring Payments by aheadWorks](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments-by-aheadworks.html)
- [modulesgarden](http://www.blog.modulesgarden.com/recurring-payments-in-magento/)
- [SubscribePro](http://www.subscribepro.com/)